# How to report CPU and memory usage per user time-series data using Cloudera Manager

Tags: hadoop, memory-management, report, cpu-usage, cloudera-manager

Trying to get a report on time-series data for CPU and memory usage using Cloudera Manager.
I'm interested in getting a report like below:

Date/Month |   CPU-usage |   Mem-usage |   User

Dec - 2014   |    x1 mins  |   y1 GB    |   user1

Dec - 2014   |    x2 mins  |     y2 GB   |   user2

Nov - 2014   |    n1 mins  |     n2 GB   |   user2

...

The idea is to get the compute usage distribution between users on a Cloudera cluster, get it by week/month and use it as a component of a pricing model.

I don't find `user` available in the `time-series attributes` of Cloudera to build the tsquery: http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CM4Ent/4.7.0/Cloudera-Manager-Diagnostics-Guide/cmdg_tsquery.html

Is it possible to get a tsquery for this report on Cloudera Manager?